# Modifying MBR entries after implementing Windows 7 image

Tags: windows-7, mbr, windows-pe, wim

I have a computer whose hard disk I recently formatted. As soon as I implement a .wim image in the computer using the WindowsPE disc with imagex utility, two entries are shown in the mbr menu: one for the previously installed system and another for the new one.

How can I edit this menu so that only the actual system appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BCDEdit` from an elevated Command Prompt. Next, check the identifier of the other OS between `{}`. Once you identify the ID of the other operating system, type `BCDEDIT /delete {long-id}` and press Enter.

Comment: Make sure to +1 it then :P